# How to use sync_to_async() in Django template?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

I am trying to make the Django tutorial codes polls into async with uvicorn async view.
ORM query works with async view by wrapping in sync_to_async() as such.

```py
question = await sync_to_async(Question.objects.get, thread_sensitive=True)(pk=question_id)
```

But I have no idea how to apply sync_to_async or thread inside Django templates.

This code fails saying 'You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.' Or any other way to work around this?

```py
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
```

I use Python 3.10, Django 4.0.4 and uvicorn 0.17.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found several solutions for that:

It's not safe. In your settings.py add:

```
import os
os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"
```

Or get your Question object in separate function:

```
@sync_to_async
def get_question(question_id):
    return get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)

question = await get_question(pk=question_id)
```

Or without splitting (works with Django 4.1+):

```
question = await Question.objects.aget(id=question_id)
```